# Getting the Keys of a Dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have a Dictionary of Dictionarys of Array of Objects. Just like this:

"
A

...Alabama

......Array of Objects

...

L

...London

......Array of Objects

...Lisbon

......Array of Objects

"

How can I get the Keys of the L Dictionary, I mean, how can I get "London, Lisbon, ..."?

I need to populate a tableView with the citys, and, when didSelectRow..., shos them on a Map.

Showing them on a Map - no problem, but I'm having trouble in getting the Keys to populate the tableView.

Thanks a lot,

RL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *KeysForL = [[parentDictionary objectForKey:@"L"] allKeys];
```

Note that the sort order of this array is undefined. You should probably sort it before you use it in a table view.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is this

```
    //This will print out all your cities for "L"

NSEnumerator *keyEnumerator = [[mainDictionary objectForKey:@"L"] keyEnumerator];
while (NSString *currentKey = [keyEnumerator nextObject])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", currentKey);
}
```

More efficient as it won't copy all your keys to the array that is returned from the allKeys method but i suppose usually it won't matter

Comment: The OP needs to populate a table, and tables refresh in essentially random-access order, so while useful in loops, the keyEnumerator is less useful in this case.